# AWS EB and Node ExpressJS server security

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, express

I am new to AWS and Linux and was looking through expressJS docs where it is recommended that the root owner of the ExpressJS server is dropped to a normal user with minimum privileges.

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){  
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));  
    process.setgid(config.gid);  
    process.setuid(config.uid);  
});
```

source: https://blog.liftsecurity.io/2012/12/07/writing-secure-express-js-apps

I created an AWS ElasticBand Linux server, deployed my code and logged on via SSH and created a group and user via

```
sudo groupadd testGroup
sudo useradd -g testGroup testUser
```

I ran **id -a testUser** and took the user and group values uid=502(testUser) gid=502(testGroup) groups=502(testGroup) and I assigned them to the main.js, the logs pipped out the following error

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){  
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));  
    process.setgid(502);  
    process.setuid(502);  
});


/var/app/current/main.js:182
        process.setgid(502);
                ^

Error: EPERM, Operation not permitted
    at Error (native)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/main.js:182:17)
    at Server.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at emitListeningNT (net.js:1263:10)
    at nextTickCallbackWith1Arg (node.js:430:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:352:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:444:11)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
```

I tried putting in the user and group names instead and got the same error message.

Any ideas here?

Comment: did you set own root folder : `chown testUser:testGroup /var/app/current` ?

Comment: Hi Thanh, Thanks for your comment, I did not set the root, just tried that but same result... node-express@0.0.0 start /var/app/current
> node ./bin/www

process.env.NODE_ENV is set to (ignore this on local instance): production
thid is the env production
setting new id in production mode

/var/app/current/main.js:182
        process.setgid('testGroup');
                ^

Error: EPERM, Operation not permitted
    at Error (native)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/m

Comment: Sorry I missed, set chown for testUser user a and testGroup `chown testUser:testGroup /var/app/current`